# Does external sharing (link and/or direct sharing) with M365 users (external) result in user creation in AD as guest user?

Tags: permissions, security, sharepoint-permissions, external-sharing

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/what-s-new-in-sharing-in-targeted-release

> Recipients of secure external sharing who also use Microsoft 365 in
> their organization can sign in using their work or school account to
> access the document. After they have entered the one-time passcode for
> verification the first time, they will authenticate with their work or
> school account and have a guest account created in the host's
> organization.

When using the above approach to assign permission to a folder in a document library, then does it mean guest user is created in AD by link sharing or direct access?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, a guest user is created in AD both by link sharing and direct access.

The first time they access the folder, they need to verify themselves using a one-time passcode. After they verify themselves, they sign in using their own work or school account. At this point, a "guest user" account is created for them in your organization's AAD. This happens whether you shared the folder with them directly, or if you gave them a link to the folder.

Comment: I tried this and can confirm that link sharing doesn't result in guest user creation in AD